# How to loop through all assets and check for a key, if the key matches, continue and display all assets? PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a collection of `$liquidAssets` and I want to loop through all of them and display only the `$liquidAssets` which maches the `key`, how could I do this? Do I need to firstly make a collection an array?

```
public function displayAssets()
{
    $name = 'name';
    $token = 'token';
    $themeId = '123';

    $assetAPI = new Asset($name, $token, $themeId);

    $assets = $assetAPI->all();
    $liquidAssets = collect($assets->assets)->where('content_type', 'text/x-liquid');
    $liquidAssets = $liquidAssets->all();

    foreach($liquidAssets as $asset) {
        $response = $assetAPI->get($asset->key);
        dd($response);
    }
}
```

The logic is this:

- loop through all assets
- check if in array there is a key ld+json
- display all assets with ld+json

Now I get only the assets of a one asset

Answer (score 0):

```
        public function displayAssets()
        {
            $name = 'name';
            $token = 'token';
            $themeId = '123';

            //$assetAPI = new Asset($name, $token, $themeId); // Is this model populated with assets rows? if yes this must be: 

            $liquidAssets = Asset::where('content_type', 'text/x-liquid')->get(); // already filtered

            //$assets = $assetAPI->all(); // this is wrong since you are trying to get data from a new object 
            //$liquidAssets = collect($assets->assets)->where('content_type', 'text/x-liquid'); // same here
            //$liquidAssets = $liquidAssets->all(); // same here

            foreach($liquidAssets as $asset) {
                $response = $assetAPI->get($asset->key);
                dd($response);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. But I get an error 'Call to undefined method App\Shopify\Asset::where()';
$assets = $assetAPI->all(); display all assets without filters;
$liquidAssets = $liquidAssets->all(); display all assets filtered;
But don't know how to do a foreach for all items, I can make to work only for one item.;